# Getting xsd restrictions of specific xml element

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Is it possible to get restrictions of specific element when I'm parsing XML file in Java?

For example, if I have a schema:

```
<xs:element name="MyString" minOccurs="0">
  <xs:simpleType>
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
   </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

when I get node MyString during XML file parsing I want to be able to acquire information that its restrictions are `xs:string` and **maxLength = 100**.

Comment: [Check JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend this [project](https://github.com/krasa/krasa-jaxb-tools).

It is the same jaxb plugin as Puce linked, but with proper maven project and some improvements.

Answer (score 2):

You could look for/ write a JAXB plugin to generate Bean Validation Annotations (JSR-303), e.g.:

http://metro.1045641.n5.nabble.com/JAXB-plugin-to-generate-Bean-Validation-Annotations-JSR-303-td5598189.html

Comment: Can you explain to me step by step how to install this plugin?

Comment: Hmm, the documentation referenced at http://java.net/projects/maven-jaxb2-plugin/pages/Home isn't reachable anymore...